# ASP.NET : ImageButton Image Doesn't Update inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an **ImageButton** inside an **UpdatePanal**, `OnClick` event, Some process is preformed on same image. than Image save on same location.

Problem is, The Code Behind Executes Successfully, But result doesn't show on Webpage

ASP Code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>  
            <asp:ImageButton  ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ImageUrl="~/Sel_Img/test.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> Code Behind

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap((Server.MapPath(@"/Sel_Img/test.jpg")))
   Bitmap bmp = Some_Process(bitmap);
   bitmap.Dispose();
   bmp.Save(Server.MapPath(@"/Sel_Img/test.jpg"));
   ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "../Sel_Img/test.jpg";
}
```

---

When i reload Page Manually, Results shown as expected, But `Onclick` Event the results does not appear , I.E *Changes in Image Doesn't Appear*.

Comment: does  image on your  folder changes according to your code? does your image visible after on-click event?

Answer (score 1):

The change doesn't appear because the image is in the browser cache. To force a refresh, you can append to the URL a different query string every time the image is modified:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "~/Sel_Img/test.jpg?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
}
```